# How to make css !important property work for all elements new style in only one declaration?

Tags: html, css

I'm making my blog design responsive on small screen sizes but when i want to change the style of a pre-styled element it changes only when `!important` is added to its css style. This is css example -

```
  .post {margin-left:10px!important;height:300px!important;}
  .post img {width:200px!important;height:200px!important;}
   a:link {color:green!important;}
```

HTML-

```
  <div class='post'> 
  <img src='photo.gif'> Here is the link of a very informative aricle <a href="/">Link</a>
  </div>
```

This is only a example, my css and html code is very long . Here in css style you can see each style contains `!important` property. Almost in every element's css i have to add `!important` otherwise element style becomes inherited. Is there any way in css to declare `!important` property only once and element's new style will work without adding `!important` to it.

Comment: I see bad things coming ahead of you... also answer is that there's no shortcut for this

Comment: Better approach would be to make your overwriting selectors more specific than the old ones. Maybe just add a class to body and use that.

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't use !important like that unless it's only needed. !Importatn forces teh browser to render something as you require. Using it carelessly is going to cause messy code and real headaches for anyone that's maintaining the site.

You should either make the appropriate fixes where it is needed. Keep in mind that:

inline css + !important > css file !important > inline css > css file.

Also if you declare something twice for example a class `.some-class{}` the properties of the later one will overwrite the properties of the previous classes. But keep in mind the !important thingy...

I would suggest you do it once as you should and save your self from future headaches...

And for further reference: http://www.w3schools.com/css/ & http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

Answer (score 0):

There is no way `!important` can be used to apply for whole of the CSS file. However you can change the order of your CSS files the way they are called. For example for iphone web pages you can use the meta tag and your CSS will be applied accordingly.

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=320"> // iphone
    //CSS Rules for iphones 
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=768">  //tablets
    //CSS Rules for tablets
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of no reason to use important in this way, if your styles inherit something you don't want chances are you have a selector issue.

If you need to override default styles for a particular reason try using an ID.

I suggest to you reading on selectors best ways to use them. !important should not be used for reasons other than not having access to original css.